# Полностью ли yield замещает собой необходимость реализовывать IEnumerator?

Tags: c#

`yield` позволяет легко создавать перечисления. Собственно вопрос, а его возможности полностью покрывают собой `IEnumerator` или в каких-то случаях все таки есть профит в ручной реализации `IEnumerator`?

На вскидку мне кажется, что через `yield` можно организовать перечисление любой самопальной коллекции.

Comment: я думаю смысл реализации `IEnumerator` есть в том случае, когда вы пишите свой тип коллекции

Comment: @Yaroslav тем не менее разве yield'ом нельзя описать ее перечисление? сделать цикл while с yield и пошло поехало. Так по идее, даже самопальный односвязный список можно перечислить.

Comment: можно и односвязный список можно сделать

Comment: `https://habr.com/post/311094/`

Comment: yield можно рассматривать как синтаксический сахар введённый в какой-то из старых версий шарпа, я как-то в учебных целях расписывал состояния yield, чтобы понять логику работы. А раз это сахар, то на нём можно выразить всё то же самое, только покороче.

Answer (score 5):

**Между ними нет ничего общего.**

Рассмотрим такой пример. Имеется класс Гараж, содержащий в себе автомобили.

Вариант без `IEnumerator`:

```
public class Garage
{
    private List<Car> workingCars;
    private List<Car> brokenCars;

    public void AddCar() { }
    public void RemoveCar() { }

    public IEnumerable<Car> Cars()
    {
        return workingCars.Union(brokenCars);
        //foreach (var car in workingCars.Union(brokenCars))
        //    yield return car;
    }
}
```

Перечислить автомобили можно так:

```
var garage = new Garage();
foreach (var car in garage.Cars()) { };
```

---

Вариант с `IEnumerator`:

```
public class Garage
{
    private List<Car> workingCars;
    private List<Car> brokenCars;

    public void AddCar() { }
    public void RemoveCar() { }

    public IEnumerator<Car> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return workingCars.Union(brokenCars).GetEnumerator();
        //foreach (var car in workingCars.Union(brokenCars))
        //    yield return car;
    }
}
```

Перечисление теперь работает непосредственно по самому объекту, без вызова дополнительного метода или свойства:

```
foreach (var car in garage) { };
```

---

Таким образом `yield` *упрощает* перечисление коллекций и т. п., но *не заменяет* возможности `IEnumerator`.

Энумератор позволяет трактовать сам *объект* как коллекцию. И ничем другим это не сделать. А как внутри реализовано перечисление - с помощью `yield` или без него - не важно.

Comment: Немного не то. Ведь я ничего не говорил про отсутствие интерфейса IEnumerable, а я говорил про то, что имеет ли смысл делать кастомныый IEnumerator.

Comment: @iluxa1810 - Ok, упростил, убрал интерфейс.

Comment: А разве не IEnumerable позволяет трактовать сам объект как коллекцию? Имплементируем этот интерфейс и можем перечислять в foreach.

Comment: @iluxa1810, foreach не проверяет интерфейсы, он сразу ищет метод getenumerator в классе. Просто реализация IEnumerable **гарантирует** наличие метода getenumerator. Это достаточное условие, но не необходимое

Comment: @iluxa1810 - C# хоть и язык со строгой статической типизацией, но в нём есть несколько финтов ушами с утиной типизацией. [Duck typing in C#](https://medium.com/@Mareks_082/duck-typing-in-c-f89e8e1ac37b)